# How can I access change month event in extjs datefield or in datepicker

Tags: events, extjs, datepicker, listener

I want something like this:

```
{
  xtype:'datefield',
  editable:false,
  fieldLabel:'date',
  listeners:{
    monthChange:function(picker){
      alert("selected month and year")
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any event for month change? If not, how can I write it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of extending 'Ext.date.Picker' as there is no 'monthchange' event:

```
Ext.define("YourCalendarPicker", {
    extend: "Ext.picker.Date",
    ...
    update : function(date, forceRefresh){
        var me = this,
            monthViewChange = me.isAnotherMonthView(date);
        me.callParent(arguments);
        if (monthViewChange){
            me.fireEvent("monthviewchange", me, date, me.activeDate);
        }
        return me;
    },
    ...

    /**
     * return true if the given date is in a different month view of the actual calendar date
     * @param {Date} date
     * @return {Boolean}
     */
    isAnotherMonthView: function(date){
        var activeDate = this.activeDate || date;
        return date.getYear() != activeDate.getYear() || date.getMonth() != activeDate.getMonth();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a monthChange event exactly, but you can listen when someone picks a new date, then maybe you could compare the month to see if it changed?  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-event-select

A little more info would be helpful if this isn't the problem you are trying to solve.